# How to redirect joomla url with parameter?

Tags: .htaccess, url

How to redirect in .htaccess joomla jevents url with parameters?

urls:

```
http://www.mysite.pl/szkolenia-theta/registration.detail/-?id=364&edet=366
http://www.mysite.pl/szkolenia-theta/registration.detail/-?id=364
```

to

```
http://www.mysite.pl/szkolenia-theta/year.listevents
```

I tried

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=364&edet=366$
RewriteRule ^http://www.mysite.pl/szkolenia-theta/year.listevents/ [NC,R,L]
```

but this doesn't work

Comment: Could you be more specific?  What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: redirection doesn't work